# Signal demodulation in a frequency mixer

Tags: electronics, signal-processing

Let's assume we have a signal $f(t)=A\sin(\omega t)+B\cos{\omega t}$.

In order to isolate the '$A$-part', the signal is mixed with an oscillator signal $g(t)=\sin(\omega t)$ generating a constant term:

\begin{align}
f(t)g(t)& =A\sin(\omega t)\sin(\omega t)+B\cos{\omega t}\sin(\omega t)\\
& = \frac{A}{2}(\cos{((\omega-\omega)t)}-\cos{((\omega+\omega)t)}) 
+ \frac{B}{2}(\sin{((\omega+\omega)t)}-\sin{((\omega-\omega)t)})\\
& = \frac{A}{2}-\frac{A}{2}\cos{(2\omega t)}+\frac{B}{2}\sin{(2\omega t)}.
\end{align}

This signal is sent trough a low-pass filter. Now I expect to get an output signal $A/2$, in literature however I often find $A$ as the output of the low-pass filter.

Is this just a nitpick, which is ignored? Am I missing something?

Comment: The $\pm$ is ignored in the mixer because it has no physical significance, after all the output phase varies $2\pi$ over a full wavelength. To find whether $+$ or $-$ you have to recover the *real* phase of the signal with a so-called unique word that is usually placed in the preamble and then periodically repeated to overcome cycle slips, range variation, etc.

Comment: Sorry, there were wrong signs in my question (edited): I expect the output signal to be $A/2$, however it is often desribed as $A$ only. I am confused about the factor of $1/2$ which seems to be neglected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mixer is not a numerical multiplier. Notice that your g(t) has an amplitude $1$; if it were $B$ then your calculation would result in $AB/2$ (with or without $\pm$). But it has the wrong dimension, it is either $volt^2$ or $amp^2$, or whatever. A mixer, not a multiplier, has a "conversion gain" (usually given in dB's), say, $k$ so that when its ports are properly terminated then the output voltage amplitude can be written as $kAB$ where the inputs are $Acos(\omega_1 t+\phi_1)$, $Bcos(\omega_2 t+\phi_2)$, and its output is $kABcos((\omega_1 -\omega_2)t+\phi_1-\phi_2)$. The conversion gain $k$ is specified for every mixer; in reality, $k$ depends on frequencies $\omega_1, \omega_2$, amplitudes $A,B$, temperature, humidity, etc. In *theoretical* books, not in practice, these dependencies are just ignored, and to simplify argument $k$ can also be dropped when performing the simplest idealized linear system (receiver) analysis.